# How to display second button after the click on first button?

Tags: javascript, html

How to display second button after the click on first button??

I mean, when The user clicks on one button, he should see another button, on click of which he should return to his previous button!! Cyclic event kind of...
I wanted to do this using Java script and HTML.

I tried to use 'onclick' but it dint work!! Help!!

This is what I used..

```
    `<body>

 function alert()
{
  alert("54");
    // <input type="button" id="btnSer" value="Back"/>
}

  <input type="button" id="btnSearch" value="Search" onClick="alert();">


</body>`
```

Comment: You can use jQuery, for example

Answer (score 3):

Something like this?

```
<button id="button1" style="display:block;" onclick="document.getElementById('button2').style.display = 'block'; this.style.display = 'none';">Button 1</button>
<button id="button2" style="display:none;" onclick="document.getElementById('button1').style.display = 'block'; this.style.display = 'none';">Button 2</button>
```

Answer (score 2):

here is the code using simple plain javascript : (*note that naming your function alert() isnt smart because there is already a predefined function in js called alert)

**Javascript Code**

```
function addBtn(){
  document.getElementById('btnHolder').innerHTML = '<input type="button" onClick="javascript:removeBtn();" value="click" />';
}

function removeBtn(){
  document.getElementById('btnHolder').innerHTML = '';
}
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="btnOne"><input type="button" onClick="javascript:addBtn();" value="click" /></div>
<div id="btnHolder"></div>
```

this code is not tested but it should work, let me know if you have any other questions

Comment: The `javascript:` isn't needed. Anything within the `onclick`'s quotation marks is treated as javascript.

Comment: yea I know, but thats a habit I have :) it doesnt really break anything so I just do it.